# GLSL for loop acting weird

Tags: opengl, for-loop, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I tried to implement something in glsl to do texture splatting, but the for loop is acting weird and gives different results for code that does exactly the same.

Code 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
 if(i == 1) {
  float fade = texture2D(alphaTextures[i], texCoord.st).r;
  vec4 texCol = texture2D(textures[i], texCoord.ba);
  texColor = mix(texColor, texCol, fade);
 }
}
```

Code 2:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
 if(i == 1) {
  float fade = texture2D(alphaTextures[i], texCoord.st).r;
  vec4 texCol = texture2D(textures[i], texCoord.ba);
  texColor = mix(texColor, texCol, fade);
 }
}
```

The if statement is just for testing purposes so that it should give the same result. The only difference is the loop condition. I really have no idea why only Code 1 gives the correct result. Here are two pictures:

[Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2p5e.png)

[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIcG0.png)

The result should be like in picture 1.

Comment: What is "texture splatting"?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_splatting

Comment: "*The if statement is just for testing purposes so that it should give the same result.*" Why should it give the same result?

Comment: Originally i tested it without the if statement and 7 textues, but the seventh texture made the whole result look completely different. The if statement should only let element 2 of the array through regardless of the texture count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030711/glsl-array-of-textures-of-differing-size), you can't iterate over a sampler array. The index `alphaTextures[i]` is invalid, you can only use `alphaTextures[1]`.

This changes in GLSL 4.00+ (OpenGL 4.0+), where you can have a variable index, but it cannot be from a shader input/derived value.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that Graphic processors don't like branched texture fetches.

Try this instead:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    float fade = texture2D(alphaTextures[i], texCoord.st).r;
    vec4 texCol = texture2D(textures[i], texCoord.ba);

    if(i == 1) {
       texColor = mix(texColor, texCol, fade);
    }
 }
```

(disclaimer) i am only guessing and this error is really weird.