# OpenGL - sampler array limit?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have two sampler arrays in my fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D shadowMaps[12];
uniform samplerCubeShadow shadowMapsCube[12];
```

This works fine on my pc with opengl 4.2, however on my laptop (opengl 3.1) I'm getting the error 'array size too big'.

If I set it to 8, it works fine. Arrays of other types can be far larger however, and I can add more sampler arrays with a max size of 8 without a problem. So, how is this limit determined?

After lowering the array size to 8 the compilation works, but the linking fails silently (The log is empty and glGetError() returns 0).

If I declare each sampler individually (uniform sampler2D shadowMap1;uniform sampler2D shadowMap2; etc.), neither of these errors occur.

Comment: How are you then accessing to those samplers? Bare in mind that depending on your OpenGL version, accessing to samplers array using loops is not permited. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12031821/988027

Comment: I was in fact using a loop to access them. Hm... the article mentioned array textures, but there doesn't seem to be a texture array type for samplerCubeShadow. Does that mean I'll have to declare them individually and access them inside the loop through if-conditions, or is there another way?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at this: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Non-uniform_flow_control

Comment: It means you have to use an _integral constant expression_ for the index. No matter what else you do, it's what ends up being in the index that matters for pre-4.0. Running a loop is fine, as long as you're not using the loop counter as index.

Comment: Thanks, I've worked around the problem now. It's still failing to link if I have more than a total of 16 samplers in my shader (Again, only on my laptop with opengl 3.1). Is there a way to retrieve the max amount of samplers you can have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to take two things into account.

First, bear in mind that depending on your OpenGL version, accessing to samplers array using variables inside loops is not permited. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031821/988027

Secondly, quoting from the [**OpenGL wiki page**](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Texture_image_units), there are a maximum amount of texture units you can use at the same time:

> OpenGL contexts have a maximum number of texture image units, queriable from the constant GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS​.

Probably, [**this answer**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/how-many-textures-can-usually-i-bind-at-once) will help you. Particularly, have a look at the shader [**resource limitations**](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader#Resource_limitations).

Comment: `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS​` is not the best limit to query in this case. There is also a per-stage limitation: (e.g. `GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`. It is guaranteed to be at least 16 for all stages in desktop GL. But this limit is the one that actually restricts the number of samplers that can be used in a single shader invocation, the other limit is the total number of texture image units (48+ in GL3, 80+ in GL4).

Comment: Just to clarify, a "texture image unit" is different from an "image unit" (ARB_image_load_store)?

Comment: OpenGL wiki page's link is dead