# Is there a way to bypass max fragment samplers in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm quite new to OpenGL ES but I'm trying to render multiple 2D images on the screen at once (`uniform sampler2D` and `texImage2D`, ...) however when I try to render more than 16 textures at once I get:

`The number of fragment samplers (21) is greater than the maximum number allowed (16).`

which I've learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524535/opengl-sampler-array-limit) and by looking at [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader#Resource_limitations) there's a hard limit to the number of textures I can bind at once. However, for my particular application, I need to render about ~30 images at once. Is there any workaround and is there any particular way I can render that many images?

Edit: Combining several images into one big image doesn't work very well in my case.

Comment: "*I need to render about ~30 images at once.*" What is your fragment shader actually doing that you need to index so many images in the same draw call?

Answer (score 0):

The only bypass I know is to put multiple images in one and bind this large texture and extract this images via texture coordinates.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really work for my particular use case

Comment: Why is this not working in your particular use case?

Comment: It's not very viable for my particular application